# modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'efivarfs': No such device

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, uefi, modprobe

when I run `efibootmgr` command:

```
efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/sdb --part 1 --loader /EFI/syslinux/syslinux.efi --label "Syslinux" --unicode
```

I get this error:

```
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
```

when I try to load the module `efivarfs`, I get following error:

```
modprobe efivarfs
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'efivarfs': No such device
```

I am using self compile kernel, and i do have `efivarfs` support:

```
CONFIG_EFIVAR_FS=m
```

so why can't I load the module ?

I am using kernel 6.1.45 on Debian 12

## UPDATE:

I have just tested on Debian Live-CD booted system, and I get the same error:

```
modprobe efivarfs 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'efivarfs': No such device
```

Comment: are you booting UEFI or Legacy mode? what is the output of `sudo efibootmgr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've booted in Legacy BIOS compatibility mode, the firmware cannot make UEFI runtime services available to the running OS, and so UEFI variables cannot be manipulated. In this situation, the Linux kernel will not present a `/sys/firmware/efi/` directory at all, and so `efivarfs` cannot be mounted, as the kernel module fails to communicate with the firmware's UEFI runtime services.

Most modern installation and Live-CDs are prepared to be bootable both in legacy and UEFI modes, so you'll have to be really careful to boot from external media **in UEFI mode** if your system has the BIOS compatibility support module (CSM) module enabled.

The writer of the system firmware can decide whether the system will prefer legacy or UEFI-style boot, or make it selectable in the BIOS settings. Unfortunately the user interface to these settings is not standardized - each vendor can do it differently.

Generally, when starting to install the first operating system to a new computer, you should decide whether to use UEFI or legacy BIOS, and if possible, **adjust the BIOS settings to allow that boot mode only.** Completely excluding the "wrong" boot mode makes it easier to avoid mistakes.